# Playwright keep data when error is thrown in test

Tags: javascript, typescript, exception, testing, playwright

```
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

test.describe('tests', () => {
    let strings: string[] = [];
    
    test('test 1', async () => {
        strings.push('a');
        throw new Error();
    });

    test('test 2', async () => {
        expect(strings).toContain('a');
    });
})
```

In the provided test, how to keep the value of 'strings' after an Error is thrown? Right now it leads to 'strings' being empty. Without error throw both tests pass.

`playwrgiht.config.ts` has `fullyParallel: false` so that tests run in sequence.

Comment: If you're answering your own question, please post it as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), [not as an edit to the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question). When editing, [please avoid UPDATE: as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged). Thanks.

Comment: Added `test.fail()` call in the `catch` section: test will fail but all steps will be executed
`test.fail(true, error);`

Comment: That's a comment. Please post an answer using the answer textarea below. Thanks.